# Find least similar/relevant document with Lucene

Tags: java, search, solr, lucene, similarity

Is it possible to kind of revert the scoring functionality in Lucene such that a search returns the least similar documents in the index?

Specifically, I want to execute a MoreLikeThis Query (the query itself is a document) and instead of getting the most relevant documents, it shoud return the least relevant/similar documents.

How would this be achievable? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always sort by "score, asc": ascending instead of descending.

Keep in mind that in order to be considered at all, there must be at least be some similarity or else the doc won't be in the recall at all.

Or you can negate the query: filter out all docs that are "like this". Sorting then becomes pointless, as these docs are all equally (fully) distinct from the query.

Comment: Thank you. For everyone with the same problem: I have implemented the reverse sorting with `Sort sort = new Sort(new SortField(null, Type.SCORE, true));` and the negated query with a `BooleanQuery`, where a `MatchAllDocsQuery` must occur and the `MoreLikeThis` Query must not occur.